# Troubleshooting Azure SQL connection issues

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP.NET application that is using Entity Framework 6 to access data stored in an Azure SQL database. I've run into a bit of a problem connecting to the database as a whole.

If I spawn a new database instance on Azure, start my app in the debugger and step through it, I'll see that it connects without a problem, can access the seed data and all is well (inserts work without a problem, but this occurs whether I change the data or not).

However, if I restart the debugger and at all points after that attempt to connect to the database when my app restarts, the connection will fail. If I set a breakpoint and look at the Context value in the Locals window, I have the following error as the value for all DbSets:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation
>   timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.

Despite having a try/catch around the logic, no exception will be thrown. If I step into/out of/over this, the application will just run indefinitely and never complete.

If I do a rollback to the $InitialDatabase and then re-apply the automatic migration (via update-database), I still cannot connect to the database, however if I delete the database in Azure, spin up a new one, set up the new connection information in the Web.config file and execute all over again, it'll work like a charm one time. After that, it'll fail to work again, despite no other changes to the application.

What's going on here and why is this behavior occurring? If there's an underlying problem here, how could I tell what it is and how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After making no headway, I rolled-back to a previous version of my code from when it was working fine about three weeks back. I've updated all the logic to match what was in the latest build, I just haven't updated any of the assemblies yet. It's working perfectly fine and connecting every time now, so apparently this is the fault of one of the as-of-yet unidentified dependencies.

If I ever determine which one, I'll update this answer accordingly.